# no me funciona la funcion file_put_contents... de php

Tags: php, php5, php7

Hola buenas noches me gustaria saber porque no me crea el archivo **gente.txt** ? me dijeron que puede ser permisos de crear o editar archivos, pero como haría eso en wampserver? Muchas gracias aquí les pongo el código.

```
$fichero = 'gente.txt';
// La nueva persona a añadir al fichero
$persona = "John Smith\n";
file_put_contents($fichero, $persona, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Es correcto, el fichero no se crea/escribe porque al parecer el usuario que ejecuta el script no tiene permiso para escribir en ese directorio. Debes usar un directorio en el que ese usuario tenga permisos de lectura/escritura. Por seguridad dedica un archivo solamente para eso, no lo mezcles con otros directorios donde guardas archivos más sensibles, sobre todo si vas a otorgar permisos a usuarios de nivel inferior o a todo el mundo.

Comment: Que error te marca  cuando corres ese código?

Comment: ya lo arregle amigo muchas gracias por la intencion de ayudar :).